# Ruby Rails, global function available to all controllers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

This is probably a stupid question, **can you have a function available to multiple controllers**?

I have 2 controllers

```
class C1Controller < ActionController::Base
 def add(input_value)
  @output_value = input_value * 2
 end
end
```

now I would like to **use this** add function **in another controller** like so

```
class C2Controller < ActionController::Base
 @new_value = add(2)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define that function in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, and it will be available in all controllers.

Comment: Thanks! Cant beleive I have overlooked this, guess Im too hungry to think straight! Lunch time :)

Answer (score 2):

`ApplicationController` can be used for this.

Make sure your other controllers are derived from `ApplicationController` and not directly from `ActionController`, as they should be. Then you can configure filters, common methods etc in the single `ApplicationController`.

But it might be wise to define a parent controller and have your controllers derive from it, as the `ApplicationController` is not really meant for random code sharing, but for specific purposes like filters and forgery protection.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define the function in a helper and then include this helper in your ApplicationController. As follows:

```
include SessionsHelper
```